# Periodic/Oscillating Loss Function for Pytorch CCNN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I’m training a CNN on ImageNet, and I’m seeing some odd, periodic oscillations in my loss function. The curve looks generally correct, but you can see clear oscillations as the curve flattens out. I’m capturing the loss every 100 mini batches, and since my batch size is 128 and my training set is ~100k images, this means that it takes 10 steps to go through the data. So the periodicity I see here is that the loss increases over the course of 10 steps, and then drops suddenly at the start of a new epoch and then progressively increases until the next epoch is reached.

I'm showing most of my training code below (not showing it in its entirety for brevity). I’m resetting the “running_loss” to zero at the beginning of each epoch, and at the end of every set of 100 mini-batches. Does anyone have any perspective here? I don’t know whether I’m doing something wrong in the way I’m computing/collecting the loss, or if there’s something more fundamental wrong with my model.

```
train_data = ImageDataset(train_file_list, transform=transform)        
train_data_loader = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=128, shuffle=True, num_workers=4)

alexnet = AlexNetPyTorch(NUM_CLASSES)
alexnet = alexnet.to(device)
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(params=alexnet.parameters(), lr=3.0e-4, weight_decay=5.0e-4)

history = {}
history['loss'] = []
history['val_loss'] = []
history['accuracy'] = []
history['val_accuracy'] = []
step_increment = 100
for epoch in range(30):

    running_loss = 0.0
    running_val_loss = 0.0

    for step, data in enumerate(train_data_loader):
        alexnet.train()
        X_train, y_train = data
        X_train = X_train.to(device)
        y_train = y_train.to(device)

        # forward + backward + optimize
        y_pred = alexnet(X_train)
        loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y_train)

        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # print statistics
        running_loss += loss.item()

        if step % step_increment == step_increment-1:    # print every 100 mini-batches

            # Compute validation loss
            with torch.no_grad():
                alexnet.eval()

                _, preds = torch.max(y_pred,1)
                train_accuracy = torch.sum(preds == y_train).item()/len(y_train)

                X_val, y_val = validation_data
                X_val = X_val.to(device)
                y_val = y_val.to(device)
                y_pred = alexnet(X_val)
                val_loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y_val).item()

                _, preds = torch.max(y_pred,1)
                val_accuracy = torch.sum(preds == y_val).item()/len(y_val)

                history['loss'].append(np.mean(running_loss/step_increment))
                history['accuracy'].append(train_accuracy)
                history['val_accuracy'].append(val_accuracy)
                history['val_loss'].append(val_loss)

                print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f acc: %.3f val loss: %.3f val acc: %.3f' %
                      (epoch + 1, step+1, running_loss/step_increment, train_accuracy, val_loss, val_accuracy))

                running_loss = 0.0
```

[image: Loss Function]

Comment: Since you are plotting the running loss (it increases (since you add) till you reach the end of 100 mini-batches) it will oscillate. You could try plotting the loss only at the end of every epoch. Also see this [link](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/#loss) about oscillating loss in neural networks. It may be helpful.

Comment: Is that actually right? I'm plotting the loss at the end of every 100 mini-batches. At the end of every 100 mini-batches  - and/or at the beginning of every epoch - I reset the running loss to zero. So what it looks like to me is that in any given epoch, the running loss successively increases from one mini-batch to another, and it's only when the next epoch is reached that there's a step change in the value of the loss function.

Comment: The running loss will of course increase, since it involves addition. Better to look at the loss after every epoch (for plotting purposes). Or you should plot the actual loss after every 100 mini-batches rather than the running loss.

Comment: Appreciate your continued dialog here. I think the confusion here is that I'm setting the running_loss back to zero at the end of every 100 mini-batches. Consequently, it looks to me that within a given epoch, I compute the average loss (running_loss/100) for the first 100 mini-batches, record a value, then reset to zero and compute the average loss for the next 100 mini-batches and get successively larger results...and so on through the course of that epoch.